# Why second method of these classes are performing their functions as long as they are not called?

Tags: python, sockets, oop

here i have server and client that can connect together and send message.but second method*`(def run(self):)`* of these classes in both server and client did not called why they are send and receive message?(Why these methods working without calling them?)

---

### code of server that uses socket and Thread:

```py
from threading import Thread
import socket


class SendingThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, mySocket):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mySocket = mySocket

    def run(self):
        # write code to send data continuously
        while True:
            data = input()
            self.mySocket.send(bytes(data, 'utf-8'))


class ReceivingThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, mySocket):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mySocket = mySocket

    def run(self):
        # write code to receive data continuously
        while True:
            msg = self.mySocket.recv(1024)
            print(msg.decode('utf-8'))


# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, # internet address family => IP v4
    socket.SOCK_STREAM # TCP
)
# bind socket with a port number
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 2010))
# keep System_1 in listening mode
s.listen()
# accept the incoming connection request
mySocket, address = s.accept()
# create a thread to send data
sendThread = SendingThread(mySocket)
# create an another to receive data
receiveThread = ReceivingThread(mySocket)
# start both threads
sendThread.start()
receiveThread.start()
```

---

### code of client that uses socket and Thread:

```py
from threading import Thread
import socket


class MySendingThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, mySocket):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mySocket = mySocket

    def run(self):
        # write code to send data to System_1
        while True:
            data = input()
            self.mySocket.send(bytes(data, 'utf-8'))


class MyReceivingThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, mySocket):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.mySocket = mySocket

    def run(self):
        # write code to receive data from System_1
        while True:
            msg = self.mySocket.recv(1024)
            print(msg.decode('utf-8'))


# create a socket object
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# send a connection request
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 2010))
# create a thread to send data => System_1
mySendThread = MySendingThread(s)
# create a thread to receive data from System_1
myReceiveThread = MyReceivingThread(s)
# start both threads
mySendThread.start()
myReceiveThread.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendingThread` and `ReceivingThread` in server and `MySendingThread` and `MyReceivingThread` in client inherit from `threading.Thread`

Have a [look at the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-objects):

> The Thread class represents an activity that is run in a separate
> thread of control. **There are two ways to specify the activity**: by
> passing a callable object to the constructor, **or by overriding the
> `run()` method in a subclass**. No other methods (except for the
> constructor) should be overridden in a subclass. In other words, only
> override the `__init__()` and `run()` methods of this class.
>
> **Once a thread object is created, its activity must be started by calling the thread’s `start()` method. This invokes the `run()` method in
> a separate thread of control**.

When you call `start()` it invoke the respective `run()` method you override in the child class.